# Difference between raster subsets as defined by another raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r, correlation

I wish to determine whether there is a relationship between slope and the Corine land cover class pastures. i.e. whether areas defined as pasture have a different slope to non-pasture areas.

I've tried some of the statistics tools in Arc but haven't had any success. Thus far I've:

1. Extracted the pastures land cover class from the Corine raster
2. Created a binary raster of pastures (pasture = 1, not pastures = 0)

How do I compare those slopes categorised as pasture and those that are non-pasture?

Has anybody calculated anything similar?

Comment: Landcover is a categorical variable. You can't (or at least shouldn't) calculate a Pearson correlation coefficient with one variable as classes. The problem is that the numerical value assigned to each class is arbitrary. If it were at least ordinal level data, you would be able to apply Spearman's rank correlation coefficient.

Comment: It sounds to me like instead you want to use something like a t-test to see if there is a significant difference in the means of pasture vs. non-pasture land.

Comment: The data is categorical, making a correlation erronious. You want an ANOVA, t-test, which is not available in ArcGIS. Try a statistical software. You can likely do this in Excel as well, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: search for nonparametric tests of association, Chi-Square, Mann-Whitney U etc will be some of the variants for the parametric tests list in several of the posts above. Also a good place to check is the Cross Validated site on Stack Exchange.  That is the statistics data site in the stackexchange family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [R software](http://cran.r-project.org/) is a good solution. You can read your rasters, extract values for the sub areas and then run an ANOVA, t-test or whatever else you might fancy. Remember to check whether your data are normally distributed so you can pick your test. Here are the basics:

```r
# read rasters
slope = raster("~/dir/dir/file.tif")
land = raster("~/dir/dir/file.tif")

# extract relevant values
slope.past = getValues(mask(slope, land=="pasture"))
slope.not = getValues(mask(slope, land!="pasture"))

# run a t-test (unlikely this is the best test)
t.test(slope.past, slope.not)
```

Comment: Your approach is not memory safe and your are correct, a t-test is not a robust solution. When working with large data it is often helpful to think in terms of sampling approaches. Multiple realizations of a random field can be very informative.

Answer (score 4):

It is very unlikely that this problem follows parametric assumptions. I would recommend exploring nonparametric group tests, available in R, such as: Mann-Whitney (wilcox.test),  Wilcoxon Signed Rank (wilcox.test), Kruskal Wallis (kruskal.test), Friedman Test (friedman.test).

You could also apply a Monte Carlo sampling approach, lbl_test in coin or bootstrapping using boot. A sampling framework would make the problem more tractable and the results much more robust.